# uitextfield clears when delete is pressed

Tags: ios, uikit

I am having an issue where pressing the delete key on the keyboard clears the entire UITextField as if I'd pressed the clear button. It only happens the very first time you press the delete key on that screen. I've checked that 'clear when editing begins' is not checked, and this is NOT a secure entry textfield.

Comment: do you change any textfield's properties or use some event handlers?

Comment: I changed none of the properties, I'm only using the UITextFieldDelegate methods, but none of them clears the field (except textFieldShouldClear). It only clears the whole field the very first time I press delete, every time after that it only deletes a single character.

Comment: Has no one else seen this before?

Comment: I'm seeing this too. From what I can tell, it's a bug in iOS 6.

Comment: Did anyone figure out a solution? I'm having the same problem, sort of... I have an email text field, and a secure entry password text field. If I enter text into the email text field, then press delete key, normal behavior - only one character is deleted. However, If I enter text into the email text field, then make the password text field active, then make the email text field active again, and then press the delete key - all characters in the email text field are deleted.

Comment: Experiencing same behavior as @danbretl.

Comment: Also, not having this issue when deployment target is iOS 4.3, only when 6.0, regardless of version running on device.

Comment: Same problem as @danbretl here, with iOS 6.1. Doesn't matter what kind of keyboard I have in the clear text field. If I never focus the secure text field, the problem doesn't occur. Also, seems it has been fixed in REDACTED.

Answer (score 2):

it looks like it's the behavior if a UITextField's keyboard type is UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress. When I switch it to another type, the backspace does not have that behavior. Not sure what to do about it though.

Answer (score 0):

may be changing return type to defaults work.
I had the same issue but changing keyboard returnTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
solved my issue, hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 0):

In IB you have to have the clear button (the X) show up (so they CAN wipe it out if they want).  I chose "Appear when editing" so it appears when they start typing.